# Как найти все вхождения строки в файле и заменить на другую строку

Tags: bash, macos

возможно тривиально но все же. Есть файл 'file.txt' - в нем некоторое количество строк:

```
export ENV1 = '1'
export ENV2 = '2'
export ENV3 = '3'
```

Необходимо bash скриптом находить строку где есть вхождение ENV1 и заменять на другое значение - ENV1 = '5'

Пробовал -
 **sed -i '' 's/ENV1/export ENV1 = '5'/g' file.txt**
но безрезультатно - не заменяет а добавляет. ОC - macos catalina. Cпасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проблема в том, что **sed** в маке не тот же **sed**, что вы привыкли. Вам нужно поставить GNU Sed

для установки выполните

```
brew install gnu-sed
```

появится новая программа **gsed**, тогда команда `gsed -i '' 's/ENV1/export ENV1 = '5'/g' file.txt` отработает корректно.

если хотите полностью заменить **sed**, то нужно исполнить просто `brew install gnu-sed --with-default-names`, при котором в **/usr/local/bin/** появится нужный **sed**

Почему у вас возникает данная проблема?

```
*'s/ENV1/export ENV1 = '5'/g'*
```

- s/../g - заменить все строки(s) во всем файле(g)
- между ними написано: искомое значение ENV1 заменить на export ENV1 = '5', поэтому, в конце вы получаете `export export ENV1 = 5 = '1'`

я бы порекомендовал сделать так

```
1) sed -i -e "s/export ENV1.*/export ENV1 = '5'/g" file.txt 
2) sed -i    "s/export ENV1 = '1'/export ENV1 = '5'/g"  file.txt
```

в первом варианте заменить все, что удовлетворяет регулярку на новое, а во втором - заменить точный текст.

оба варианта работают на маке. gsed не нужен

**UPDATE**

Что делать, если нужно менять URL?

менять разделитьель с `/` на `~`

```
  /tmp VALUE="http://127.0.0.1"
VALUE="http://127.0.0.1"
➜  /tmp cat test.txt | sed  -e 's~export ENV1.*~export ENV1='"${VALUE}"'~'
cat test.txt | sed  -e 's~export ENV1.*~export ENV1='"${VALUE}"'~'
export ENV1=http://127.0.0.1
export ENV2 = '2'
export ENV3 = '3'
```

Comment: спасибо большое за совет но все же если мы отбросим  sed - в какую сторону посоветуете посмотреть еще - инсталяция дополнительных пакетов немного трудозатратно в моей ситуации.

Comment: я обновил ответ и дополнил ее

Comment: в sed поступают переменные - выражение должно быть что то типа sed -i -e "s/$ENV.*/export $ENV=$VALUE/g" $FILE но почему то дает ошибку sed: 1: "s/ENV1.*/export E ...": bad flag in substitute command: '/'

Comment: при ENV=ENV1, VALUE=5, выражение `sed -e "s/export ${ENV}.*/export ${ENV} = '${VALUE}'/"` отлично работает.   покажите больше информации.

Comment: есть функция 

`function env_to_file() {
  FILE=$1
  ENV=$2
  VALUE=$3
   if grep $ENV $FILE; then
     sed -i '' "s/export ${ENV}.*/export ${ENV}='${VALUE}'/g" $FILE
   else
     echo 'export '$ENV' = '$VALUE'' >> $FILE
   fi
}`

Comment: замените `sed -i '' ` на `sed -i -e` (исчезла лишняя ' ' и появился флаг -e)  посмотрите внимательно на пример.

Comment: да я вижу - ваш пример отлично работает - ошибка из за того что я пробую передать урл в переменную то есть - `sed -i -e "s/export ENV1.*/export ENV1='http://127.0.0.1'" file.txt

Comment: потому что вы в конце забыли добавить знать `/`. полное выражение будет `sed  -i -e "s/export ENV1.*/export ENV1='127.0.0.1'/"`

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1` - sed плюеться на хттп://

Comment: я добвил в ответ кусок кода, которая решает вашу проблему

Comment: спасибо Вам за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Можно как-то так:

```
sed -i '' "/ENV1 =/s/'.*'/'5'/g" file.txt
```

если на какие-то особенностий синтаксиса BSD'яшного sed'а не напоролся... само собой выражение можно расширить/сузить в зависимости от допустимого содержимого конкретного файла...

Comment: к сожалению привязки к '1' не будет - все парсить нужно именно по "ENV1 =". Потому что даже в маке выражение типа -  sed -i '' 's/export ENV1 = '1'/export ENV1 = '5'/g' file.txt уже отлично срабатывает - но как видите нужно не так.

Comment: @RizakFamily, тогда так... лучше сразу выкладывай настоящий файл или максимально приближенный к боевому — без этого сложно угадывать, что именно нужно...